# How to add an extra source directory for maven to use only when running tests or when debugging?

Tags: java, maven

I have a set of configurable plugins that are being debugged.

They would not exist in a build of the main program but are part of the debugging regimen.

How to add them as resources that can be used in tests and debugging but not included in the final build?

The tests and debugging depends on the program locating the proper plugins and configuration directory/folders, compiling sources on the fly and then testing them with also stepping through them.

As a result, the source files used during the test must reside in the normal folder used during run-time.

I have this:

```
 <build>
        <resources>
                <resource>
            <directory>conf</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

The problem is that the resources are now being added to the final compile, which is not what is desired.

Comment: Have you tried just putting them under `src/test/java/org/mypackage` ?

Comment: see added info above.

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Netbeans with Maven POM project.

Comment: On phone, so I won't post a complete answer, but you'll need to use multiple build profiles if you want different source paths for the same (non-test) lifecycle phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep the ressources in a different folder. as mentioned in the comments, you could use the standard archiecture (src/main/resources and src/test/resources) or as you tried you can define a test resources folder:

```
<build>

<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>testresources</directory>

    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Helpfull links you'll find here: [access the ressources in junit](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/07/how-to-get-file-resource-from-maven-srctestresources-folder-in-junit-test/) and [the maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

Comment: Works!  Adding them as TestResources prevents them from being added to the jar or target classes. And debugging works purfectly.